# oh-my-posh module is working slowly inside git directories

Tags: git, oh-my-zsh

I am using oh-my-posh for PowerShell and it is extremely slow inside git repos. In regular directories, if I press enter, a new line appears instantly. However, if I press enter inside git repos it takes 1-2 seconds for a new line to appear. Here's my profile:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JanDeDobbeleer/oh-my-posh/main/themes/schema.json",
  "blocks": [
    {
      "alignment": "left",
      "segments": [
        {
          "background": "#91ddff",
          "foreground": "#100e23",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "folder_icon": "",
            "folder_separator_icon": "  ",
            "home_icon": "",
            "style": "agnoster"
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "path"
        },
        {
          "background": "#95ffa4",
          "foreground": "#193549",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "git",
          "properties": {
            "display_status": true,
            "display_stash_count": true,
            "display_upstream_icon": true
          }
        },
        {
          "background": "#906cff",
          "foreground": "#100e23",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "properties": {
            "prefix": "  "
          },
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "python"
        },
        {
          "background": "#ff8080",
          "foreground": "#ffffff",
          "powerline_symbol": "",
          "style": "powerline",
          "type": "exit"
        }
      ],
      "type": "prompt"
    }
  ],
  "final_space": true
}
```

I have tried setting `display_status`, `display_stash_count` and `display_upstream_icon` to false as well, but that does practically nothing for the performance. Any ideas?